# Argument list too long

Tags: android, android-studio

I just wanted to build my app in Android Studio. However, after I changed somethings in my XML files, now it is giving the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.io.IOException: Argument list too long
> Argument list too long

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.827 secs
```

I don't know what this is. I've searched a lot on the Internet, but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Can you include the full output from the build? I can't tell which phase of the build is failing. Also, if you get the output from building via the command line with the --stacktrace option, like the error message says, it will provide more info.

Answer (score 1):

Try with Build > Clean project, then Rebuild. Android Studio is not yet a finished product.

Comment: @sidon 4 more years later and the problem is still there at least on OSX.